# How to create new columns from key: value pairs in big query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have a table A with the structure:

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "abc" | "123" |
| 1 | "def" | "346" |
| 1 | "xyz" | "789" |
| 2 | "abc" | "462" |
| 2 | "def" | "464" |
| 3 | "abc" | "362" |

However this representation proves to be a bit difficult to process in our infra pipelines, so I'm trying to create a new table/materialized view in big query with the following structure:

| id | "abc" | "def" | "xyz" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "123" | "346" | "789" |
| 2 | "462" | "464" | NULL |
| 3 | "362" | NULL | NULL |

The number of keys is guaranteed to be small (<100). What's the best way to do this using only SQL/JavaScript UDFs in Big Query?

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
execute immediate format('''
select * from your_table
pivot (any_value(value) for key in (%s))
''', (select string_agg(distinct "'" || key || "'") from your_table))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]